# Problem Inputting Formula Into Wolfram Alpha

Tags: statistics, wolfram-alpha

I am trying to calculate the following:

$1-\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{\binom{2,500}{k}\binom{247,500}{8,500-k}}{\binom{250,000}{8500}}$

I am inputting this into wolfram alpha like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-sum%5Bbinom%5B2500,k%5D*binom%5B247500,8500-k%5D%2Fbinom%5B250000,8500%5D,%7Bk,0,4%7D%5D) but I can't seem to get the formula correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about the syntax of Wolfram Alpha entry, rather than the mathematics involved.

Comment: @T.Bongers Where should I go to get help with this?

Comment: Maybe the mathematica se site, or the Wolfram Alpha documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to add a space after the commas as:

1-sum[binom[2500, k]*binom[247500, 8500-k]/binom[250000, 8500],{k,0,4}]

Comment: It sill uses k=1 to K=0.4 for some reason.

Comment: The proposed numbers are HUGE (try Stirling approximation to have an idea). You have not thought that the problem might come from a machine limit (or deliberate limit) imposed on the calculation.